# User model extends Authenticatable and extends Model (for eloquent purpose)

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a User Model that extends Authenticatable. But I want that User Model to extends Model at the same time. This is because I want to make the hasmany() relationship in this Model. Do you guys have a way on how can I do this?

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
......
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Authenticatable has already inherited Model class.

If you follow `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` you will find that it is inherited from a Model class. So, your User model has the same features that your other models have.

Therefore, your `hasmany()` relation should work without any issues. 
Refer to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) for more information.

Comment: got it! thank you. will refer the documentation more.